# Redirecting disk read/writes in Python

Tags: python, redirect, io, websocket

Would it be possible for a python application which runs on a server to run another python application and intercept all HDD reads and writes made by the child application. Then send them through to a client application over a web socket so that the operation can be executed on the client rather than the server?

Comment: This could require low-level OS changes, so you should specify yours

Answer (score 1):

Intercepting real hard disk access is impossible without OS-specific changes.

A easier approach would be intercepting **file access**.

If you're `import`ing the python module that does the writes, this can be done through simple [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) - just replace the file objects by instances of a custom class you create. You can even replace `open`, if you *really* want to.

If you're launching a separate process (such as with `subprocess`), and want to keep doing so, I suspect this will be impossible with pure python (without modifying the called program)

Some possible system-level solutions on linux:

- [using `LD_PRELOAD` to intercept library calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).
- [Write a FUSE program](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) to intercept the filesystem access